# Edit HTML output from Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jira, confluence

I have some apps running over a Tomcat Server (Jira, COnfluence & Jforum).

I want to add to all of them a banner at the top of the page.

Is there any way to modify the output of all of them to show it? Basically, I want to ad a frame for showing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with [sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/). I think sitemesh is configured using a JavaEE filter so you could change the web.xml of each application to add that filter.